# My new iPad Air language

Tags: ipad

My iPad Air language is correctly set up in English UK. Whenever I write (such as right now) it wants to change the words to French. Also the keyboard Go and Search keys are in French. I am nowhere near France! Help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a French keyboard activated.
Go to Settings > General > Keyboards > Keyboards and select the edit button on top right. Delete the keyboards you don't want.

[image: keyboards iOS 8.4]

Alternatively, tap the globe symbol on the left side of the keyboard to rotate between active keyboards.

If you keep it pressed you can select from a list

[image: globe on iOS keyboard pressed down to select keyboard]

Comment: You are welcome @Stan. If the answer solved your problem, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.